# How to refactor this code to get a source from property files?

Tags: java, properties, hash-map

I want to get the source of these files, but I don't know if I'm efficient.

I get the source of the file, put the source in a `list`, so I put this in a `hashmap` with the key is the `version` of file and the `values` are the `list`.

```
private Map<String, List<String>> loadXmlNodes() {

    Map<String, List<String>> mapNodes = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> nodes = XmlUtil.loadNodes1_10();

    mapNodes.put("1.10", nodes);
    nodes = XmlUtil.loadNodes2_00();
    mapNodes.put("2.00", nodes);

    return mapNodes;
}

public static List<String> loadNodes1_10() {

    List<String> node = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        InputStream inputStream = XmlUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("nodes1.10.properties");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(inputStream);

        for (Object value : properties.keySet()) {
            node.add((String) value);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return node;
}

public static List<String> loadNodes2_00() {

    List<String> node = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        InputStream inputStream = XmlUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("nodes2.00.properties");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(inputStream);

        for (Object value : properties.keySet()) {
            node.add((String) value);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return node;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple of inefficient things you do, and there's some better-practice items too.

First, let's take one of the methods:

> ```
> public static List<String> loadNodes2_00() {
>
>     List<String> node = new ArrayList<>();
>
>     try {
>
>         InputStream inputStream = XmlUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("nodes2.00.properties");
>         Properties properties = new Properties();
>         properties.load(inputStream);
>
>         for (Object value : properties.keySet()) {
>             node.add((String) value);
>         }
>
>     } catch (IOException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
>
>     return node;
> }
> ```

`node` is not a great name for something that is a list. It is typical in computer programs for `node` to point to just a particular element in a list, stack, or whatever, not the whole thing.

Something like `result`, or `names` would be better.

Then, you are not closing the InputStream. This is bad practice, and is a bad habit to be in. Java7 allows the try-with-resources statement, which is ideal for this code.

Now, there is the less-commonly-used [method stringPropertyNames()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#stringPropertyNames%28%29) available on Properties. It is useful here, instead of iterating on the `keyValues()`.

Why are the `loadNodes1_10()` and `loadNodes2_00()` methods public? Do they need to be? They should be private to the class if they are not used.

Constant values embedded inside code are often [called 'Magic values'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants). In this case, the values are Strings. You should declare a constant for your resource names....

Putting it all together, how about this method:

```
private static final String RESOURCE_NODES_2_00 = "nodes2.00.properties";
private static List<String> loadNodes2_00() {

    List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    try (InputStream inputStream = XMLUtil.class.getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream(RESOURCE_NODES_2_00)) {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(inputStream);
        names.addAll(properties.stringPropertyNames());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return names;
}
```

This is neater, and more efficient, and it closes all the streams correctly.... but... apart from the method name, and the file name, your two methods are identical. What you should do is generalize the method:

```
private static List<String> loadNodes(String resourcename) {

    List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    try (InputStream inputStream = XMLUtil.class.getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream(resourcename)) {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(inputStream);
        names.addAll(properties.stringPropertyNames());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return names;
}
```

Now, in your calling method, you can change your code to:

```
private Map<String, List<String>> loadXmlNodes() {

    Map<String, List<String>> mapNodes = new HashMap<>();
    mapNodes.put("1.10", loadNodes(RESOURCE_NODES_1_10);
    mapNodes.put("2.00", loadNodes(RESOURCE_NODES_2_00);

    return mapNodes;
}
```

This should simplify the code a whole lot.

If you need the two methods `loadNodes1_10()` and `loadNodes2_00()` to be public, I would make them simply:

```
public static List<String> loadNodes1_10() {
    return loadNodes(RESOURCE_NODES_1_10);
}
```

All the best, and enjoy.

---

### EDIT:

If you want to return a `Map<String,Map<String,String>>` instead, it will look something like:

```
private static Map<String,String> loadNodes(String resourcename) {

    Map<String,String> names = new HashMap<>();
    try (InputStream inputStream = XMLUtil.class.getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream(resourcename)) {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(inputStream);
        for (String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
            names.put(key, properties.getProperty(key));
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return names;
}
```

and then you would have to adjust the other methods that call this respectively.

Comment: I´ve changed my collection to a hashmap, is there any way to put the register like in list?

Comment: @DiegoMacario not sure what you are asking... what's a register?

Comment: I want to put the pair of properties files like this...map<String, Map<String, String>> the key of the map I´m going to put the version...and in the value, I´m going to put properties source file.

Comment: @DiegoMacario See the edit...

Comment: great, I read about try-with resources

Answer (score 4):

1. Instead of `Map<String, List<String>>` you could use Guava's `Multimap` ([doc](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap), [javadoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)) which was designed exactly for that.
2. Are you sure that in case of an `IOError` your clients want an empty list? If that's some optional data it can be fine but it could be possible that instead of this you should propagate the exception to the caller and signal the error to avoid processing invalid data.
3. See also:

   - [Avoid printStackTrace(); use a logger call instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10477607/843804)
   - [Why is exception.printStackTrace() considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7469316/843804)

Comment: I don´t know Guava´s project...I´m going to see

Comment: The advice in itself is good, but this feels more like a "quick random note" (i.e. comment) than an answer.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg thanks for your comment, but it can help me. I´m gonna read.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over the `Properties.keySet()` should give you keys, not values.
Therefore, these loops are either buggy or misleading:

```
for (Object value : properties.keySet()) {
    node.add((String) value);
}
```